# Gatling Java REST API Automation: how to implement API call with Auth that expires (hence token has to be regenerated after every hour or so)

Tags: gatling

So I am able to do this fairly easily in JMeter, I wanted to try out if I can do this with Gatling.
(Note: I am using Gatling Java DSL and JDK 1.8, not planning to use higher version java.)

Problem:

1. Auth Token API Call --> generates a token expiring in 50min (this cannot be changed)
2. Call REST API with this token
3. Do Reauth (step1) if API throws 403

My flow: (made some progress on this)

1. Call Auth API --> save token to session
   (Checking if status is 403 or when script is initializing (status is not in session) --> only then generate new token)
2. Reuse the same threads (users) to call APIs. (looping users)
   No need of creating new thread/users every time. Since we will store the http.response.status on the session, we will use the same users for identifying when to do reauth. If you create new thread/users every time, their session data will be clean when they complete and the 403 will not be propagated to do reauth.
3. Call REST API --> save http.response.status on session --> if response is 403 (this should cause reauth) --> loop back to step1

Is there a better way to implement this. I am not able to identify a cleaner solution. Also a little stuck at the last part, just created a rudimentary POC. I can share my code if you need reference.

I assumed this would be a very common problem with REST API Testing, since the authentication tokens are always with some expiry. But I dont see any obvious/easy solution.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to completely bypass per virtual user authentication. If so, you could have 2 scenarios:

- one that would periodically take care of preemptively fetching an auth token (meaning the loop period is less than the token max age) and store it in a global variable.
- your real scenario that would use the current global auth token. Just make sure to delay the injection profile (`nothingFor`) so the first scenario has time to fetch the first token.

Comment: Even in real production, the token for calling APIs are cached and not generated for every call. This I am talking about internal systems talking to each other, so behind a secure network. This is not some one online calling an API that everytime they have to prove who they are (auth each time).  
Thanks for your suggestion, its quite similar to what I am doing right now, I am saving the token to a static variable and only when I get a 403, I am going to get another token. There will be some failures (403) in the mean time.

Comment: Not static variable, rather session variable per user/thread. So auth happens once per thread and they continue using it, until it expires.

Comment: I'm saying you don't need a token per virtual user. A global one would suffice to make it work. In real production, you're saying that tokens are cached, then this cache is global, right?

Comment: I catch your drift. Totally agree that instead of per thread we can have a static variable with the token sharing across all threads (contained in a separate scenario). How will we regenerate the token when it expires if its in another scenario? Sorry if this is a stupid question, I am new to Gatling.

Comment: As I explained, it's easier to generate a new one preemptively instead of waiting for the current one to expire. If the token's max-age is 30 min, generate a new one every 29 min.

Comment: Will Try it. I was hoping there was a more elegant way of doing this.

While I am at it, I had another question. 
I have another piece of code that generates the payload for the API call. I have observed, if I just put it like `.body(StringBody(PayloadBuilder.getPayload()))` where the getPayload() returns a String object, this doesnt work and I get the same object every time. I had to add another `exec` to call the getPayload() method and save the String on the session object. Is there any other way to do this? I dont like this solution.

Comment: .body(StringBody(session -> PayloadBuilder.getPayload()))
Reminder: one question per topic

Comment: Thanks a lot, based on your recommendation I have written the code. Seems to be working as a POC. Will post it in the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Stephane's response, I have come up with the following solution:
The java file can be found here.

[GitHub link](https://github.com/vishalendu/gatling_poc_api_with_auth)

Created 2 scenarios.

- Calls to /authorize endpoint and saves the `token` to a static variable
- Calls to /order endpoint with the authorize header updated with token

The images below show requests, and the order of calls based on the load profile.
`/authorize then 4 /order calls` --> first auth header
`/authorize then 4 /order calls` --> updated second auth header

Image1: Shows first 4 calls having `Authenticate: Bearer 202212363211618239`

[image]

Image2: Shows second set of 4 calls having `Authenticate: Bearer 202212363211718325`

[image]